# Not getting ArithmeticException in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to run below program and expecting `Arithmetic Exception` because we are `dividing double value by zero but getting Infinity as output`.

This is below program. `But if we are using int instead  of double then getting Arithmetic Exception`

```
public static void main(String z[]) {
    Double a = 10.0;
    Double b = 0.0;
    System.out.println(a/b);
}
```

Output: `Infinity`

```
public static void main(String z[]) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.println(a/b);
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at (Test.java:94)
```

> Can someone please explain why we are getting Infinity for Double
>   value?

Comment: @AndyTurner Could this behavior perhaps also have something to do with that floating point arithmetic is not exact?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.
>
> ...
>
> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> - Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity.

Floating point division can have a non-exceptional result because there is a special value to indicate it. There is no such special value for integer division, so returning any integer result would be incorrect; the only option is to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In IEEE 754 floating point operations, dividing a value by 0 (resp. 0.0) is well-defined and results in an "infinite" value, either positive or negative, depending on the involved values.

In integer domain, no such thing is defined and thus you get an `ArithmeticException`.